# JavaScript xPath

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

I have following sample html:

```
<html>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="product-context">
            <div class="product-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-8">
                        <div class="product-info-buy p-15">
                            <div class="product-price-wrap">
                                <h5>23%</h5>
                                <h5>2,527,200</h5>
                                <span class="product-price">
                                    <div>1,965,000</div>
                                    IRR
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to find nodes that contain "IRR" as innerText. I use the following xPath in my JS:

```
const xpath = '//*[not(self::script or self::style)][contains(text(),\'IRR\')]';
```

But evaluating using

```
const result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

returns nothing. what is wrong with my code? or how can I find nodes that have specific string somewhere in their innerText?

Comment: What kind of node, an element node? Try `//*[not(self::script or self::style)][text()[contains(.,\'IRR\')]]`

Comment: Yes, element node, that worked well, thanks @MartinHonnen

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this in pure JS, without XPath

```
const find = (node, text) => {
    if (node.innerText?.includes(text)) {
        for (const child of node.childNodes) {
            const result = find(child, text);
            if (result) return result;
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

and then call

```
find(document.childNodes[1], 'IRR')
```

to find the span element that contains necessary text.

Comment: He is asking about xpath, not new solution

Comment: @ToorajJam I wouldn’t be so critic, because it can help other people struggling with the same problem.